# Kubuntu 15.04 installation error "Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141"

Tags: hard-drive, boot, gparted, kubuntu

During the installation of Kubuntu 15.04, I get the error "Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141".
I did some researcher on the topic and found that one popular reason for the problem is having another Linux distribution installed on the hard drive. At first I fought that this is not my problem because I only installed windows on this laptop. But when I looked at my hard drive using the LiveUSB I remembered that there was an invisible partition which came with the laptop. I didn't remove it during windows installation, and I think it might cause the problem.
On the other hand I don't want to remove it without first checking here if it can cause damage to my computer. Some files which seem to be relevant (to my knowledge take part in the booting process in windows and linux) are on it.

I know that that everything I wrote above is very vague, sorry for that. The only way I came up with to ask this properly is to upload the content of that disc. You can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0DdDlcpFacIfmRROFZYX0RXdEhIdHp4NVBYRXJoOTlaUi1FWUs1bmtFd3ZWeXB1cm1LTWc&usp=sharing).

If anybody knows if I can remove it, or what else might cause this problem, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try and format the root partition (/) BEFORE starting the install tool on the Live CD. I've just got past this problem myself, it seems it is a bug in the installer. So, basically I set up the root partition as ext4 before starting the installation from the live CD and all went OK. I have two other systems on my laptop - Kubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu MATE 14.04.