# Safe to remove kernel versions from previous Fedora installation?

Tags: fedora, grub2

To solve some problems with my current installation of Fedora 24 I reinstalled Fedora using the Live USB. In doing so I reused the `/boot` and `/home` partition. Everything went well and I was able to boot into the new installation.

However, in `grub` shows additional entries for the kernel versions from the previous installation and several files in remain in `/boot`; namely `config-*`, `initramfs-*.img`, `System.map-*`, `vmlinuz-*` and `vmlinuz-*.hmac`.

The solutions I found assume that all kernels were installed using a package manager and it is suggested to remove the kernels the same way. This wont work for me.

So, is it safe to remove all those files (the current kernel excepted) or could there be side effects?

Comment: Does this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/906776/kubuntu-15-04-installation-error-ubi-partman-failed-with-exit-code-141) help out at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is safe, and there should be no side effects — at least assuming you don't make any mistakes which affect the *current* kernel configuration.